# Http to https redirect blocked by CORS policy

Tags: http, redirect, https, cors, flask-cors

I am trying to do a GET (or POST) request to a localhost server from a chrome developer tools console window running on a website with https (in this case outlook.com, but it's the same for any https). If I run the same code from a website that is running on http it works fine.

The error I'm getting:

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:5000/: Redirect from 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' to 'https://127.0.0.1:5000/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://outlook.live.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I have found that https to http communication is not possible, but running the flask server on https does not help either, Flask does not even recognise an incoming request in this case.

I have a Flask app running, code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    return "bar"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The javascript I'm using for the request:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I know there are many similar questions, but none of the solutions posted yet have worked for me, how do I create a successful GET or POST request from chrome developer tools running on a https website to a localhost server (preferably Flask)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the Flask app with `ssl_context='adhoc'` to use https:

It was the browser blocking the https because the certificate was insecure.

This answer (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31900210/2208827)) worked for me:

> NOT FOR PROD
>
> Simply paste this in your chrome:
>
> `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`
>   You should see highlighted text saying: Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost
>
> Click Enable.

Also, [this blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https) explains more about using Flask with certificates.